# Classify Maps up to Homotopy from Special Cylinder to $S^4$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

[image]

Let $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ be given.

Let $F \subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ be given such that $|F| = n$.

Define an $F$-flip map on $S^4\to S^4$ by sending $x_j \stackrel{F\mbox{-flip}}{\mapsto} \begin{cases} -x_j &\mbox{if } j\in F \\ 
x_j &\mbox{if } j\notin F \end{cases}\forall j\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, where $x_j$ is the $j$th component of the $x\in\mathbb{R}^5$ vector in $S^4$.

Let $d$ be a continuous map from the cylinder to $S^4$ which obeys special boundary conditions on the two boundaries of the cylinder, $C_1$ and $C_2$:
on the circles $C_1$ and $C_2$, antipodal points get sent to "F-flipped" points on $S^4$. That is, if $k\in C_1$ and $-k\in C_1$ is its antipodal point, then we have the relation $d(-k) = F\mbox{-flip}(d(k))$ where $F$ is as defined above, and the same for every $k\in C_2$ as well.

My question: how to classify all such maps with the specified constraints up to homotopies?

---

**EDIT:** Apparently I made the wrong formulation of the condition above. It is not antipodal points on $C_1$ and $C_2$ that should be related by $F$-flip, but rather, points of the same distance to some arbitrarily-chosen fixed point on the circle (call it zero), as depicted in the following drawing:
[image]

Comment: @JesusRS, Well, except for respecting the $F$-flip condition, I don't see what other condition I could demand.

Comment: Then the restriction only affects the boundary $X=C_1\cup C_2$ of the cilinder. Perhaps the _Borsuk homotopy extension theorem_ (e.g. Engelking's General Topology, p. 428) reduces the problem to flip homotopy classes of mappings $X\to S^4$, and then to flip homotopy classes of mappings $S^1\to S^4$. I would look for some reference on _equivariant homotopy_.

Comment: It seems I made an error in the original formulation of the question. I added an edit to reflect this, I guess it doesn't change your comment, right @JesusRS?

Comment: I think it doesn´t. Affects to the equivariant formulation for homotopy classes of mappings $f:S^1\to S^4$: you want $f_t\circ\sigma=\varphi\circ f_t$, where $\sigma$ is a symmetry now, not the antipodal map, and $\varphi$ is the flip.

Comment: @JesusRS, I have thought about it and I think the classification of $f:S^1\to S^4$ with the flip condition is that when $n=4$ the equivariant homotopy group is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, where the non-trivial generator is given by $f$ such that $f$ flips signs between $0$ and $\pi$ on the coordinate that is not $F$-flipped. All other cases are trivial??

Comment: For $n=0$ it's easy to see directly. Then the flip condition only means  that everything goes to the quotient cilinder$/x\sim\sigma(x)$. But that quotient is $S^2$, hence the equivariant homotopy group is $\pi_2(S^4)$, which is trivial.

Comment: Another remark, when I say Borsuk reduces to the boundary flip-homotopy classes, I mean reduces to study flip-homotopy of two mappings from the cilinder to $S^4$ with prescribed restriction to the boundary (one representative of each flip-homotopy class $C_1\cup C_2\to S^4$. Also note that any such map extends to the cilinder because any two maps $C_i\to S^4$ are homotopic ($S^4$ is simply connected).